# GWT. Invoking method by name

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, reflection

Is it possible in simple way (JSNI?) ?
Code below to ilustrate what I want to do:

```
public class ExtColumn<T, C> extends Column<T, C>  {
        private String name;

        public String getName() { return name; }

        public ExtColumn(Cell<C> cell, String name) {
                super(cell);
                this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public C getValue(T object) {
                //return  invoke from object metod "get" + name;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried GXT (a.k.a. Ext GWT)? It handles this sort of functionality automatically through its BeanModels (i.e., binding fields to the models so you don't need to write such getValue methods).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try. But I already have project writen with GWT, is it possible to implement with native gwt tools?